# django.utils.translation does not translate but python import gettext does

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.2, I have been tasked to make a site multilingual supported. My development environment is Windows 10. I have installed "gettext" by downloading the binaries and "xgettext" --version gives me

```
xgettext (GNU gettext-tools) 0.20.2
Copyright (C) 1995-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
```

so I know get the text is working. My settings file is having the following

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
from os import path
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), 'locale'),
)
```

I have just put "de" for testing. I have run makemessages -l de and compilemessages. I have the ".po", ".mo" files as well.

In my views and in my templates, translations do not see to work.

i.e.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils import translation
output = _('StatusMsg')
hello  =  _("hello")
print(output)
return render(request, 'polls/index.html',{'hello':hello, 'status':output})
```

my template code is

```
{% load i18n %}
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> {% trans 'Welcomeheading' %} </h1>
    <p> {% trans 'welcomemessag' %} </p>
     {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
     <h1>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</h1>
     {{ status }}
     {{ hello }}
     
  </body>
</html>
```

gives me "hello" and "StatusMsg" in the template and the language code comes properly as "de".

However if use

```
import gettext
local_dir = 'C:\\workspace\\Learning\\Python\\transtest\\mysite\\locale'
de = gettext.translation('django', localedir=local_dir, languages=['de'])
de.install()
_ = de.gettext 
status= _('StatusMsg')
helo  =  _("hello")
return render(request, 'polls/index.html',{'hello':hello, 'status':output})
```

The translations come up properly. I am still trying to debug this, but any pointers in the right direction will be really helpful.